# How to rename index in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

According to our business logic every night web job deletes index and creates new one and populates it. But lately we've noticed that populating index takes about one hour. So during this time we don't have any working index in production. So currently we are thinking over the following changes:

Name of our production index is 'prodindex'. 
We want firstly to create index with name 'prodindex1', populate it and if everything is ok delete index 'prodindex' and rename index 'prodindex1' to 'prodindex'.

But now i facet problem that i can't rename index.
So is it possible in Azure Search to rename index?

Comment: I am curious to know why you need to delete index to repopulate the data. Also, can you please update your question and include details like how you're populating the data in an index.

Comment: That's not an issue right now. I know that it is possible to update data inside index. Currently i'm  investigating possible solutions. Now i'm wondering is it possible to rename index or not.

Comment: `Now i'm wondering is it possible to rename index or not` -> Currently it is not possible to rename an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to rename an index. Feel free to add a suggestion on [Azure Search UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) site.

Comment: You know the best part about voting for something Azure related on UserVoice?  It'll get your hopes up for ~7 years by being "Under Review".
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328647-support-swapping-indexes